# how to have short user defined aws s3 pre-signed url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mailto, pre-signed-url

We have need to share the aws s3 pre-signed url through email. However the generated url is very long and in our case the bucket file name are dynamic which can have long file names.

What are the option available to generate aws s3 pre-signed url with short name without exposing these parameters in the url
X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-SignedHeaders, X-Amz-Expires,X-Amz-Credential,X-Amz-Signature

how can i make this s3 url short when generating message for email and pass it to my mailto function.

Thanks
Anjana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. All that information is required in the URL.

However, you could use/create a URL Shortening Service (eg http://bit.ly), which will translate a short URL into the full URL.

The simplest version of this would be:

- Generate a pre-signed URL
- Store a shortcut in Amazon S3 with a randomized name
- Provide a link to the shortcut

See: [How to build a Serverless URL shortener using AWS Lambda and S3](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-serverless-url-shortener-using-aws-lambda-and-s3-4fbdf70cbf5c)

Answer (score 0):

Purpose of pre-signed url is to provide a [temporary access to download file from S3 where files are private by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).

If your S3 files are meant to be public, you can [mark them as such](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket), and [link to them directly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html#virtual-hosted-style-access). Or you can e.g. link [Cloudfront distribution to a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.SimpleDistribution.html), and [assign a custom domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) to that distribution. Or you can use redirect/shorten service.

WARNING: Using a service to redirect to/shorten these urls has security concerns. Final url would need to be difficult to guess/infer, so that it's long and [truly random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)

WARNING: Sending any private files via email is a security concern:

- Standard email is not encrypted end-to-end
- Possibility of human error (wrong recipient)

If your S3 files are meant to be private I would recommend a different approach: send link to a page that requires authentication and has the actual file download button with pre-signed url.